# Does jquery validation Plugin validate alphabets/characters

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to  validate characters via jquery validaton plugin?

Comment: could you be less generic and explain exactly which is the problem?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer asa accpeted if you got the info you want ..

Answer (score 2):

include this file

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Here's an example:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    myField: { lettersonly: true }
  }
});
```

It's worth noting, each additional method is independent, you can include that specific one, just place this before your .validate() call:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

> Update

**letter issue with white spaces problem solved**

You just change this `/^[a-z]+$/i` regular expression into this `/^[a-zA-Z\\ \\.\\]+$/`

Comment: Buddy. Slight problem. Its not accepting a white space in a Name Field. For example Dr. Bharat Vatwani

Comment: You just change this regular expression into  **/^[a-zA-Z\\ \\.\\]+$/** @sly_Chandan

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
});
```

Example : full

```
  $(function ()
    {
        $.validator.addMethod("loginRegex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");

        $("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "login": {
                    required: true,
                    loginRegex: true,
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "login": {
                    required: "You must enter a login name",
                    loginRegex: "Login format not valid"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```